# How do I remove arrows stuck in my body?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

While traveling down a wintry road, I encountered a man of fine tastes.  I can tell this by his great dedication to the improvement of my countenance, evidenced by the several fine body piercings he provided me entirely free of charge.

In the time since, however, I have come to regret my rash attempts at body modification.  Meter-long arrows transfixing my chest and one knee seemed quite edgy and avant-garde at the time, but the look seems to have gone mainstream.  As a result, my piercings have begun to pall and I greatly look forward to ridding myself of them.

Sadly, they have proven quite stubborn.  I have stripped, slept, healed, traveled, and battled but cannot dislodge these troublesome barbs.

Have any of you fine warriors advice for dealing with this all-too-literal thorn in my side?

Comment: Relevant: http://i.imgur.com/1eIEc.jpg

Comment: This question is phrased in a fun way, but sadly it will probably also make it difficult for people to find it when they search.

Comment: @TM. — I'll leave it to others to decide if or how much it needs edited or reigned in.  I wanted to make sure it would show up in a search for ["skyrim remove arrow"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=skyrim+remove+arrow), but otherwise just had fun with it.  :-)

Comment: I feel like I need to make an arrow in the knee joke here... But I won't.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Oo that looked like that hurt

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Some people have had success with the following:

1. un-equipping/equipping the arrows in their inventory
2. storing all the arrows in thier inventory into a chest/corpse
3. Getting shot with more arrows by a bandit, then killing that bandit.

Comment: Upon asking my faithful housecarl to disburden me of my ammunition, she deftly removed the offending projectiles.  Many thanks for your timely suggestion!.

Answer (score 16):

Provided your platform of choice is the PC, you can open the console with the back tick (`) key and enter the command

```
sexchange
```

and then Enter.  The projectile will be gone.  Then you can revert the change (or not), and carry on, my wayward son.

Comment: Yup, I always fix my unwanted piercings by getting a sex change. :p

Comment: Bethestda was probably just mocking a poorly constructed url like `piercingsexchange.com` or something? ;)