# Why do I still have arrows stuck in my arm?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove arrows stuck in my body?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35565/how-do-i-remove-arrows-stuck-in-my-body)

Obviously, at some point I have had enemies fire arrows at me but now I am still running around with 2 arrows stuck in my characters arm.

Since aquiring these, at least two weeks have passed in the game and they will not go away. Any ideas how to get rid of them ?

Comment: I could swear this is a duplicate, but I can't find the other question anywhere.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot But these are arrows aquired in fights. Not intentional piercings. Not sure its the same answer ?

Comment: @Terry Yes it is. It was just humorously formulated..

Comment: @bummzak Ahh ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spoiler:**

> Transforming into a werewolf solves the issue, at least it solved mine when I had an arrow stuck in my... knee.

Comment: Brilliant. Will try this :-)

Comment: Sadly, this is contingent upon certain character choices.  So, it won't necessarily work for everyone all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing clothes will fix this.  Not at my PS3 right now to test, but I seem to recall it working for me once.

Comment: Changing clothes doesn't help :-(